# Vertically align list items in bootstrap navbar with a set height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a navbar in bootstrap but the list items are stuck to the top when a height is set. Is there a more fluid way of centering them vertically without using margin-top.

BOOTPLY
http://www.bootply.com/Ua9pFtsUDv

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest padding the links, like so:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){

    .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 60px;
      padding-bottom: 60px;
    }

}
```

That allows the different states to take up the height of the nav bar.

[See it in this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/HPXv52dpcH)

Answer (score 0):

I just used margin-top:. Not sure if it's the most eloquent, but it works.

```
 .nav,.navbar-toggle {
     margin-top:40px;   
 }
```

Comment: The question explicitly says "without using margin-top"

Answer (score 0):

You can add flex to your navbar:

```
.navbar {
    height:140px;
    background-color:#0f254f;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

be aware of browser differences though.

Answer (score 0):

Vertically aligning navigation links is almost a universal problem when using Bootstrap. 
a workaround is :

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
 line-height: line height that you need;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment issues have to do with display properties.  If you change your display properties to table and table-cell.  You will be able to use vertical-align in your css and it will work perfectly.  Just change your css to:

```
.navbar {
    height:140px;
    background-color:#0f254f;
    display:table;
    width:100%;

}

.navbar .container {
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Here's a Fiddle showing it at work https://jsfiddle.net/vcr3okwp/